# How to edit these array of input values individually in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, next.js

Due to the nature of this input values, I am using `fill` method to generate their fields based on user's choices. This is the code:

```
  const fillArray = new Array<buyerDetails>(Number(orderData.numberOfParticipants)).fill({buyerFirstName: '', buyerLastName: '', buyerEmail: '' });
```

I passed the array to a `useRef` variable like this:  `const buyerDetailsRef = useRef<buyerDetails[]>(fillArray);`

I used `map` method to have them displayed on the screen along with html tags like this:

```
<div className="w-full flex flex-col">
{
   buyerDetailsRef.current.map((item, index)=>(<div className="flex flex-col" key={index} >

  <p className={`${ubutu.className} text-1xl text-gray-500 mt-2 pb-2`}>{index + 1} Participant Information</p>

<div className="flex mt-3 w-full"><div className="flex flex-col w-2/5 border-2 rounded-md">
 <p  className={`  text-gray-500 px-2 `}>First Name</p> 
 <input type="text" className=" outline-none border-none py-1 bg-gray-100 px-2" onChange={(text)=>handleBuyerInfo(text.target.value, 'buyerFirstName', index)}onMouseEnter={()=> setArrayIndex(index)}/></div> <div className="flex flex-col ml-3 w-2/5 border-2 rounded-md"> <p  className={` text-gray-500 px-2 `}>Last Name</p> <input type="text" className=" outline-none border-none py-1 bg-gray-100 px-2"/></div></div><div className="w-full flex mt-3 border-b-2 pb-3"<div className="flex flex-col  w-2/5 border-2 rounded-md"><p  className={` text-gray-500 px-2 `}>Email Address</p> <input type="text" className=" outline-none border-none py-1 bg-gray-100 px-2"/></div></div></div>
 ))
  }
 </div>
```

This is the function that I tried to use to update the individual input values based on their index:

```
 const handleBuyerInfo = (text: string, dataType: string, index: number)=>{
    
    buyerDetailsRef.current.find((item, itemIndex)=>{
        if(dataType === 'buyerFirstName' && index === itemIndex){
            item.buyerFirstName = text;
            return setOrderData({...orderData, buyerDetails: buyerDetailsRef.current})
        }
    }) 
}
```

It is rather updating the entire fields. For instance, if I am updating the `buyerFirstName` field for index 0, it updates the entire `buyerFirstName` values of all the rendered index. Is there a way to only update these values individually?